# How to perform two-way fixed effect Difference in Difference test?

Tags: logistic, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference, cluster-sample, covid-19

I am doing a research on the effect of Covid on fundraising success. I already implemented logisitc regression models with Covid as interaction variable but my supervisor wants me to use DiD.
I asked a colleague and he suggested "two-way fixed effect DiD". As all the countries in my sample were affected by Covid but in different times, he suggested using DiD that takes this into consideration, but neither me nor him know how to implement it.

I am trying to test the effect of an external shock (Covid) on the success of funding (binary variable) with several independent variables. I expect the DiD to judge whether Covid has influenced the relationship between successful funding (dependent variable) and the independent variables. My data contains several funded projects overtime but each project is represented only once.

The data spans over three time periods: Before covid, time 1 (1 month after Covid started) and time 2 (two months after Covid started and onwards).

I grouped the projects according to the country to have two groups: Group 1: for countries affected by Covid in time 1 onwards. Group 2 for countries affected by Covid in time 2 onwards.

After a lot of reading, I think I need to use a DiD version that combines staggered DiD (to account for treatments in different time periods) and two-way fixed effect DiD (to control for the effect of different countries).

For applicability, the following can be assumed:

1. Data name: myData
2. Dependent variable: success
3. Independent variables are "goal", "description" and "duration" (all are numeric variables). But I also have "date" and "country".

Can you please recommend a Python or R code to run this test?

Comment: Welcome. So you have two post-Covid eras, correct? One from January to March and another from March onward?

Comment: Yes. So, I will split the data into two groups of countries which exprienced Covid in different times. Group 1 would be projects in countries which experienced Covid in January onwards and Group 2 would be projects in countries which experienced Covid March onwards.

Comment: @ThomasBilach
After playing around with the data I came up with four categories:  
1. Group 1 posted in time 1 (g1t1) (number of projects: 1730)
2. Group 2 posted in time 1 (g2t1) (number of projects: 126)
3. Group 1 posted in time 2 (g1t2) (number of projects: 9164)
4. Group 2 posted in time 2 (g2t2) (number of projects: 834)
They are highly unbalanced in terms of the number of projects, I am not sure if this is going to be a problem.